# Why can scalar magnetic potential be set to zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, field-theory, gauge-theory

in the derivation of the perturbing Hamiltonian $ H=\frac{e}{m_0}A\cdot p$
in an electromagnetic field I came across a footnote that said that we can set the scalar potential $\varphi$ to zero.

I don’t understand why this is possible? Doesn’t it change the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the relationship of the electric and magnetic fields to the potentials is given by
$$\vec{E}=-\nabla\varphi-\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}$$
$$\vec{B}=\nabla\times\vec{A},$$
you actually have some freedom to choose what $\varphi$ and $\vec{A}$ are without changing the values of $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ (for example, you could add an arbitrary constant to $\varphi$ without changing the value its derivatives). This is called gauge freedom. It is possible to use gauge freedom to set $\varphi=0$ for any given values of $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$. All you have to do is change the time-dependence of $\vec{A}$ so that $\frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t}$ makes up for the loss of $\nabla\varphi$. It is possible to do this without changing $\nabla\times \vec{A}$. The choice of gauge where the scalar potential is set to zero is called the Weyl gauge.

Comment: Thank you! ;)))

Comment: I understand that if we adopt the Weyl gauge, $\text{div}\vec{A}\neq 0$ in general.